# No SortedMultiMap in Guava?

Tags: java, android, guava, android-guava

I am trying to find a way to get a sorted multimap. I checked Guava which offers two separate collection data structures that combined could answer my problem. What's striking is that SortedSetMultimap can not contain identical keys because it's a Set while Multimap is in the same symbol. What's up with that?

**EDIT**

In C++, I've got something like that, which hopefully will tell you how I intend to use similar functionality in Java:

```
  struct KeyCompare : public binary_function<pair<double,double>, pair<double,double>, bool>
  {
    bool operator()(const pair<double,double>& p1, const pair<double,double>& p2) const;
  };

  multimap<pair<double,double>, Object*, KeyCompare> _list;

  .../...

  KeyCompare key_compare;

  while (( ! _list.empty() && key_compare(_list.begin()->first, k))) {

    u = _list.begin()->second;
    v = _list.begin()->first;
```

In English: I need a map with keys being pairs of doubles referencing some object contained in the value. The map can contains multiple keys that are identicals (same pair of double numbers happens), so this needs to be a multimap or bag. When this occurs, the element can be inserted in the collection and when picking the top element, it should return one of those (doesn't matter which one). I need for the collection to be mutable because for each iteration, I am picking the lesser element and removing it from the map.

Comment: How would you want to sort your multimaps?   Like an ArrayList<String>?

Comment: Let me edit my post to provide more details

Comment: Please clarify in more detail what you want in English, which will help Java experts understand what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you possibly looking for `MultimapBuilder.treeKeys().arrayListValues().build()` ?

If you needed to pass a comparator, that might look like

```
 MultimapBuilder.treeKeys(new Comparator<Pair<Double, Double>>() {
      @Override public int compare(Pair<Double, Double> p1, Pair<Double, Double> p2) {
        return ComparisonChain.start()
            .compare(p1.first(), p2.first())
            .compare(p1.second(), p2.second())
            .result();
      }
    }).arrayListValues().build();
```

Comment: I have yet to figure out how I can build a multimap sorted by keys that are pairs with this construct. However one big downside is the first sentence in the description: "MultimapBuilder instances are immutable". I need to remove the first element for each iteration. Copying the collection each time would be very expensive.

Comment: It is the builder itself that is immutable, not the built multimap.  And to use pairs, all you have to do is pass a comparator for your pair type to treeKeys.

Comment: Would you mind adding a sample code to your reply. I am not quite up-to-speed with Guava collections.

Comment: Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: This looks really helpful. I'll give it a shot. I'll do more reading because the arrayListValues() purpose isn't clear to me?

Comment: You have to decide how you should collect multiple values for a given key -- in a set, in a list, etc.

Comment: I'm thinking about removing the [tag:android-guava] tag and replacing it everywhere with [tag:guava] and [tag:android]... do you think there's a good reason to keep the tags distinct?

Comment: @durron597 it seems to be a reference to an entirely independent project, but then, Guava is working on improving its utility for Android independently.

Comment: Android-guava isn't run by Google? It didn't even occur to me that might be the case. Well, if that's so, they should definitely be separate tags.